# Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx'-React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
          "dom",
          "dom.iterable",
          "esnext"
        ],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "react" <=error
      },
      "include": [
        "./src/**/*.ts"
      ]
    }
```

**Login.tsx**

```
   interface IUserLoginInformation {
      username: string;
      password: string;
    }

    const Login = () => {
      const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        watch,
        formState: { errors }
      } = useForm<IUserLoginInformation>();
      const history = useHistory();
    
      const [users, setUsers] = React.useState([]);
      
    
      const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<IUserLoginInformation> = data =>
        fetchLoginDeatils();
    
      return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <input defaultValue="test" {...register("username")} />{" "}
          {/* register your input into the hook by invoking the "register" function */}
          {/* include validation with required or other standard HTML validation rules */}
          <input {...register("password", { required: true })} />
          {/* errors will return when field validation fails  */}
          {errors.password && <span>This field is required</span>}
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      );
    };
    export default (Login);
```

On the above code I get the following error.I tried all the possible options on the internet. But nothing changed.In the Login code I use both javascript and type script  .I change the **"jsx": "react-jsx"** to **"jsx": "react"** as well.I put a mark where the error comes on **tsconfig.js**

```
 Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided.
```

Comment: can you try adding `"./src/**/*.tsx"` in the `include` array?

Comment: nothing changed.

Comment: try `import React from 'react'` in your tsx files

Answer (score 0):

The following is wrong as it excludes `.tsx` files like  `Login.tsx`

```
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts"
  ]
```

## Fix

Change it to :

```
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
```

## Additional tips

- After the change try to restart you IDE + terminal for the tsconfig.json to be picked up.
- Ensure there are no other tsconfig.json files.